# Javascript - property of an object in another property?

Tags: javascript, properties, object

In the following example, how do I modify the variable "sizeMod", which is a property of each object?

```
// Will be created by ids
var objs = {};

// Set up objects
$.each(ids, function(index, value){
    objs[value] = {
        sizeMod: 0
    };
    objs[value] = {
        change: function(){
            sizeMod += 1; // How do I write this line correctly?
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the second statement is destroying your original object where `sizeMod` is declared.

this should work (untested)

```
$.each(ids, function(index, value){
    objs[value] = {
        sizeMod: 0,
        change: function(){
            this.sizeMod += 1; // How do I write this line correctly?
        }
    };
});
```

you may call as

```
objs['relevantkey'].change();
```

Comment: Does "this" always refer to the top object, or does it ever refer to a nested value (in terms of json objects with multiple levels).

Answer (score 1):

see if this helps:

```
.
.
.
objs[value] = {
    sizeMod: 0
};
objs[value].change = function(){
    this.sizeMod += 1;
}
.
.
.
```